# WordPress the_content() closes divs

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode, markup

I'm hoping someone can help with this - I've been trying to debug for a while now.

I'm using a WordPress [shortcode] to display a list of FAQs on a page. The FAQs are custom post types, so it's a simple loop to display each one. I have the loop code in a separate file which I'm calling using an include within the shortcode function like this:

```
function insert_faq_list($atts) {
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'type' => '', // no selection
        'amount' => '-1', // all
    ), $atts ) );
    if (file_exists(STYLESHEETPATH.'/insertfaqlist.php')) {
        ob_start();
        include(STYLESHEETPATH.'/insertfaqlist.php');
        $content = ob_get_clean();
        return $content;
    }
}
add_shortcode('insertfaqlist', 'insert_faq_list');
```

And the loop code is thus:

```
<?php  
$paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
query_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'faq', 'posts_per_page' => $amount, 'faq_type' => $type , 'caller_get_posts' => 1, 'paged' => $paged ) ); ?>

<div class="faq-wrapper">
    <h2>Frequently Asked Questions</h2>
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?> 
                <div class="faq-item">
                    <h3><a href="#" class="show readmorelink"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                    <div class="slidingDiv">
                        <?php the_content(); ?>
                    </div> <!-- slidingDiv -->
                </div> <!-- faq-item -->
            <?php endwhile; ?> 
    <?php endif; ?>
</div> <!-- faq-wrapper -->

<?php wp_reset_query();?>
```

However, somehow there are too many divs getting closed in the final displayed page, so the formatting of each FAQ is all messed up. I've eliminated the JQuery used to 'reveal' each FAQ answer, and so I've narrowed it down to the_content() itself. If I swap the_content() for some straight text, all is displayed fine, so somehow the_content() is causing other divs to close prematurely. The FAQ posts are all straight text too, so no HTML formatting within them that might mess with the wrapping divs.

Any help appreciated. Cheers!

Comment: Looks good to me on a quick glance. Have you tested not applying the `the_content` filter, e.g. just using `echo get_the_content()` to see if it's really dependent on the content?

Comment: Janh - I hadn't thought to use 'echo get_the_content()' and now I've tested this, the output now looks correct. But I've always used the_content() and all has been fine - although not always with a shortcode in the same code combination, so not sure why it's behaving this way...

Comment: That's narrowing it down to the filters (most likely). `the_content()` basically does `echo apply_filters("the_content", get_the_content())`. Now test your shortcode that you are suspicious off, just use `echo insert_faq_list()` and look at the output. If that works too, try `echo do_shortcode(get_the_content())` to only interpret shortcodes (but all of them) in the content, but not run all the filters that are attached to `the_content`.

Comment: Okay - I've tested the `echo insert_faq_list()` and the `echo do_shortcode(get_the_content())` and they work fine too.... so we're looking again at `the_content();` - Now I'm sure this was working fine a month or so ago (when I last looked at the page) so that makes me suspect somewhere some update has made a change (for the worse)

Comment: As it's unlikely that the core filters do this (more people would have a problem), I'd search for "the_content" in the theme and the plugins. Try to disable it where ever you find it (or just temporarily disable the plugin) and see what happens.

Comment: Awesome - thank you JanH for all your assistance... just returned a TON of results for this, so I will work through these tomorrow (is nearly midnight here) and see what turns up. Cheers :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158208/discussion-between-andyibm-and-janh).

Comment: I'm seeing this (HTML I add using the_content getting "improved" but actually resulting in unbalanced tags) as well, with no plugin but my own (WP YouTube Lyte) active. Were you able to fix this @AndyiBM?

Comment: Hi futtta, yes - janh pointed me to some really badly-written conditional code (mine) which was closing a div when it shouldn't have.